# Connection String not valid - MDX query error in Power Pivot

Tags: mdx, powerpivot, mdx-query

I am trying to execute MDX query in Power Pivot.

While creating connection I have selected Model.odc. The connection string gets validated successfully by Test Connection.

In further step when I execute the MDX query and click on Validate query. The "MDX query is valid" message is displayed.
But when I click on Finish, Connection String is not valid pop-up is displayed.

I don't want to import the query data via Text. I want to apply measures on data.

I am using Excel 2016.

Any help highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]